# I am writing a function which accepts two lists of same size, if one list is the reverse of the other the function return True else it returns False?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

[image]

The function on the left of the screen is written by me while the function on the right is a solution which works.If anybody could explain what went wrong with the logic behind my code I can't seem to figure it out.I am trying to use negative index(count) for the second list while using a positive index(index) for the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Value of `len(lst2) - 1` is the greatest index value possible for lst2 because indexes are in the range `[0, ..., len(list)]` for a given list. `list[len(list) - 1] == list[-1]`. So if he subtracts `index` incremented 1 by 1, it means that he is going from the last index to the previous one and so on...

Note: you can also compare the two lists by simply reverse the second:

```py
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
    return lst1 == lst2[::-1]


print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))  # True
print(reversed_list([1, 5, 3], [3, 2, 1]))  # False
```